# Shift brackets through a equitation in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, arraylist, iterator

I've got i.e. a following expression: all variables are numerical (floats or int)

```
a+b*c+d*a+b
```

I would like to create a loop function or iteration in python 3 that shift (brackets) thorough the expression so the result is varies and with print out function, so I can track which expression belongs to which result.
It has to cover all possible combination.

i.e.

```
(a+b*c+d*a+b)
a+(b*c+d*a+b)
a+b*(c+d*a+b)
a+b*c+(d*a+b)
a+b*c+d*(a+b)
(a+b*c+d*a)+b
(a+b*c+d)*a+b
(a+b*c)+d*a+b
(a+b)*c+d*a+b
```

If we make it more difficult, so it woul dbe very nice if I could introduce a parameter, that allows to create more then one pair of brackerts, i.e. 2, and cover all possible combinations

```
(a+b)*(c+d*a+b)
....
(a+b*(c+d)*a+b)
...
(a+b)*c+d*(a+b)
...
```

and so on, all combinations that are possible

Have someone any idea, how we could solve this?

Thank a lot in advance

Comment: Since SO is not a free coding service, we ask you to demonstrate your effort by posting your code.

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about dynamically creating expressions, which can be accomplished by compiling them to bytecode.

You're looking for the built-in eval() function, which (among other things) accepts an expression as a string, compiles it to bytecode, and executes the expression as Python code.

For example:

```
>> eval('2+2')
4
```

So, all you need to do is:

1. write a function that produces every possible combination of parentheses as a string
2. pass each string to the eval method

Here is my implementation:

```
def parentheses(a, b, c, d):

    for num in range(0, 9, 2): 
        for closing_index in range(4, 13, 2):
            string_expression = ""
            list = [str(a), '+', str(b), '*', str(c), "+", str(d), '*', str(a), "+", str(b)]
            list.insert(num, '(')
            if closing_index < (num + 4):
                continue
            list.insert(closing_index, ')')
            for element in list:
                string_expression += element
            print(f'{string_expression} result: {str(eval(string_expression))}')
            string_expression = ''


parentheses(49, 2, 21, 4)
```

and the result:

```
(49+2)*21+4*49+2 result: 1269
(49+2*21)+4*49+2 result: 289
(49+2*21+4)*49+2 result: 4657
(49+2*21+4*49)+2 result: 289
(49+2*21+4*49+2) result: 289
49+(2*21)+4*49+2 result: 289
49+(2*21+4)*49+2 result: 2305
49+(2*21+4*49)+2 result: 289
49+(2*21+4*49+2) result: 289
49+2*(21+4)*49+2 result: 2501
49+2*(21+4*49)+2 result: 485
49+2*(21+4*49+2) result: 487
49+2*21+(4*49)+2 result: 289
49+2*21+(4*49+2) result: 289
49+2*21+4*(49+2) result: 295

Process finished with exit code 0
```

for more info: https://realpython.com/python-eval-function/

Comment: To add more the one pair of parentheses will be a bit difficult, but your solution is good basis for the futher extensions.

Comment: I'm glad to help! Can you kindly upvote and/or mark as solved? I'm a new member trying to build rep.